# Email notifications for low free space

Tags: sendemail, file

I want to send an email when the space on my pi's sd card is getting low. Also I would like to delete old files when disk space is very full.

I can program in Python though I have not yet done so for the pi.
I am sure sending an email would be easy in python; I would just need a way to check for disk space and delete the oldest files in python also.
Are there any existing programs or scripts that do this well? Should I just write my own?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here's a short version of bash script for your purpose:

```
#!/bin/sh
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
  echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $usep -ge 90 ]; then
    echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" |
     mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" you@somewhere.com
  fi
done
```

you have to install `sendmail` and setup a `cron` entry to run this script, according to a very [detailed explanation](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html). there's also an extended version of this script available at the same url.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ssmtp` and `mailutils` to send out emails. Just google and you will find some tutorials. You can use `ssmtp` and `mailutils` in python by using `os.system()` or`subprocess()`.

To check for file size, again, do a little googling. Here is one from [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=22180).

Here is a snippet:

```
import os

# Return CPU temperature as a character string                                     
def getCPUtemperature():
    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
    return(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))

# Return RAM information (unit=kb) in a list                                       
# Index 0: total RAM                                                               
# Index 1: used RAM                                                                 
# Index 2: free RAM                                                                 
def getRAMinfo():
    p = os.popen('free')
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i + 1
        line = p.readline()
        if i==2:
            return(line.split()[1:4])

# Return % of CPU used by user as a character string                               
def getCPUuse():
    return(str(os.popen("top -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\):/ {print $2}'").readline().strip(\
)))

# Return information about disk space as a list (unit included)                     
# Index 0: total disk space                                                         
# Index 1: used disk space                                                         
# Index 2: remaining disk space                                                     
# Index 3: percentage of disk used                                                 
def getDiskSpace():
    p = os.popen("df -h /")
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i +1
        line = p.readline()
        if i==2:
            return(line.split()[1:5])
```