# How to directly get CPU temp in Python?

Tags: python, temperature, cpu

Goal is to switch an exhaust fan at an outside data-logging station at a solar power station.  The data-collection program is written in Python under Raspbian.

For reading CPU temp at a command line, there is the `vcgencmd` command.

Example in bash:

```
echo "The CPU is at $(vcgencmd measure_temp) degrees."

The CPU is at temp=39.2'C degrees.
```

as the command returns the string "temp=39.2'C"

I've never personally seen this fail, although I know there is a question about that point.

[vcgencmd measure_temp doesn't always work](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/vcgencmd-measure-temp-doesnt-always-work)

Meanwhile, I would like to obtain the CPU temp in Python.

Back to the Goal:  the fans are controlled by `PiGPIO` calls, and during data-logging I keep my external system calls to the minimum (ie., there aren't any other than Python file I/O).  Also, it would be much preferable to get the answer as a simple floating-point value than to extract it from a return strung.

---

The question is:  How to directly get CPU temp in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, set up Python:

```
pip install setuptools
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/nicmd/vcgencmd.git
```

---

Handy `bash` script `cputemp`

```
(shebang)/usr/bin/python
import vcgencmd
CPUc=vcgencmd.measure_temp()
print str(CPUc)

chmod +x cputemp
sudo cp cputemp /usr/bin
```

Example use in `bash`:

```
echo "The CPU is at $(cputemp) degrees C."

The CPU is at 39.6 degrees C.
```

---

**Short and to the point, and in the floating data format for comparisons within the Python program..**

Comment: Good answer. Is this any faster or slower than `os.popen('vcgencme measure_temp')`?

Answer (score 17):

For those coming here from Google. 
You can get Raspberry CPU temp in Python using `gpiozero` package.

```
 pip install gpiozero
```

---

Create your `temp.py`

```
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature

cpu = CPUTemperature()
print(cpu.temperature)
```

Output :

```
$ python temp.py
56.92
```

Answer (score 13):

It has already been answered and accepted but I see that no one has brought up this alternative that doesn't depend on running a command but rather on reading from a file: **/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp**.

This file holds the temperature in milli-degrees Celsius.

```
$ vcgencmd measure_temp && cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
temp=47.8'C
47774
```

So, open the file and read the content. No need to do string processing.

Comment: From where do you get such valuable information?

Comment: This is, IMHO, the best approach. No libraries, no binary executions. Linux at its best.
Thanks for this info!

Answer (score 2):

"On Stretch there is no vcgencmd command at all."

So what is

```
 vcgencmd commands
commands="vcos, ap_output_control, ap_output_post_processing, vchi_test_init, vchi_test_exit, vctest_memmap, vctest_start, vctest_stop, vctest_set, vctest_get, pm_set_policy, pm_get_status, pm_show_stats, pm_start_logging, pm_stop_logging, version, commands, set_vll_dir, set_backlight, set_logging, get_lcd_info, arbiter, cache_flush, otp_dump, test_result, codec_enabled, get_camera, get_mem, measure_clock, measure_volts, scaling_kernel, scaling_sharpness, get_hvs_asserts, get_throttled, measure_temp, get_config, hdmi_ntsc_freqs, hdmi_adjust_clock, hdmi_status_show, hvs_update_fields, pwm_speedup, force_audio, hdmi_stream_channels, hdmi_channel_map, display_power, read_ring_osc, memtest, dispmanx_list, get_rsts, schmoo, render_bar, disk_notify, inuse_notify, sus_suspend, sus_status, sus_is_enabled, sus_stop_test_thread, egl_platform_switch, mem_validate, mem_oom, mem_reloc_stats, hdmi_cvt, hdmi_timings, file"

 vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=42.9'C
```

Comment: You are correct.  Changing Q&A to focus on Python.

Comment: translation... yes, the vcgencmd is indeed available on Stretch, and here are all its available arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see anyone else respond this way so I figured I would post it:

```
import psutil

def get_cpu_temp():
    temp = psutil.sensors_temperatures()['cpu_thermal'][0].current
    return temp

print(get_cpu_temp())
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to the other answers:

- https://elinux.org/RPI_vcgencmd_usage
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/15559/35753

Using the nice answer to [Less ugly yet reliable way to find this floating-point value embedded within a string without padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49562967/3904031):

```
import re, commands

def check_CPU_temp():
    temp = None
    err, msg = commands.getstatusoutput('vcgencmd measure_temp')
    if not err:
        m = re.search(r'-?\d\.?\d*', msg)   # https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563120/3904031
        try:
            temp = float(m.group())
        except:
            pass
    return temp, msg

temp, msg = check_CPU_temp()

print "temperature (" + u'\xb0' + "C): ", temp
print "full message:    ", msg
```

which returns both a floating point value and the original message in which it is contained.

```
temperature (°C):  49.0
full message:     temp=49.9'C
```

Comment: note `commands` is python2, it has been replaced with `subprocess`, though there are other py2-specific things in here too.

Comment: @tedder42 thanks for that! I'll try tend to this soon, but you are welcome to edit it yourself or post a new answer if you feel so inclined. I'm aware that the time is coming and 2.7 will no longer be supported and us 2.7ers need to port ourselves over, I've just been procrastinating... which reminds me that I hadn't accepted your Space answer yet... done!

Comment: I was/am still reticent to change it this dramatically. I think it's okay to just leave it, especially because there's no canonical way to do it anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

well  we gotta use python 3 here - since python 2 is not used any more
duhhh

```
import re, subprocess
 
def check_CPU_temp():
    temp = None
    err, msg = subprocess.getstatusoutput('vcgencmd measure_temp')
    if not err:
        m = re.search(r'-?\d\.?\d*', msg)   # a solution with a  regex
        try:
            temp = float(m.group())
        except ValueError: # catch only error needed
            pass
    return temp, msg
 
temp, msg = check_CPU_temp()
print(f"temperature {temp}°C")
print(f"full message {msg}")
```

Answer (score 0):

On the RPi Foundation site, there is a guide on how to make a temperature log. In it are instructions on the GPIO Python library built into Raspbian. https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/temperature-log

Comment: It [goes back](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/temperature-log/4) to same as answer given by @hg8 i.e. `pip install gpiozero` and `from gpiozero import CPUTemperature` to get the temp.