# Error when trying to read out temperature with gpiozero

Tags: gpio, python, temperature

I am new to [gpiozero](https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero). I successfully managed to make some LEDs blink, but I am struggling reading out the CPU temperature as described in the example at [gpiozero.readthedocs.io](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html).

My code is pretty short:

```py
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from time import sleep

factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='192.168.1.103')
myRes = CPUTemperature(min_temp=30, max_temp=90,pin_factory=factory)

print('Initial Raspberry Pi temperature: ' + str(myRes.temperature))
print('READY and waiting 10s')
sleep(2)
```

The error I receive is

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp'

However, on the RasPi itself, I can see the mentioned device (and temperature):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $  cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
50464
```

What do I do wrong? How can I fix that issue? Does GPIO maybe require some additional parameter?

#### References

- [How to directly get CPU temp in Python?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85415/how-to-directly-get-cpu-temp-in-python)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411115/how-to-display-cpu-temperature-in-bash-prompt

Comment: The two paths you show are not the same, are you aware of this?

Comment: @PMF: That was a copy'n'paste error, I edited my question. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the `CPUTemperature` class does not support reading from a remote Pi, even if you provide a remote pin factory.

There's an issue to add it but it's probably not a priority: https://github.com/gpiozero/gpiozero/issues/581

For now you can try doing it with pigpio itself: http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#file_open